# rails duplicate record not rendering new

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, clone, duplicate-data

all I want is duplicate an existing record. It should render new form with populated data and let me 'Create' this new record.

```
def clone
  @agreement = Agreement.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
  @agreement.clone

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render action: "new", notice: 'Agreement was successfully cloned.' }
  end
end
```

My Model

```
def clone
  self.dup()
  self.slug = nil
end
```

I get this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"agreements", :format=>nil, :id=>#<Agreement id: 1, date: "2011-12-18",...`
```

Routes

```
resources :agreements do
  member do
    post 'approve'
    get 'clone', :controller => 'agreements', :action => 'clone'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your clone method should be:

```
def clone
   clone = self.dup()
   clone.slug = nil
   clone
end
```

And the controller:

```
agreement = Agreement.find_by_slug!(params[:id])
@agreement = agreement.clone
```

ps: Why do you specify the controller and action in your routes. It's what the default would be, or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @Robin Error gone. Cloning works now. Any idea how to include has_many associations as well? I also removed the fluff in my routes, heritage from previous issue

Comment: I have been trying to find a good answer to this question for a while. This is the best one I have found. Plus it works!