# Duplicate record in Rails and populate new form with its associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, clone, rails-activerecord

I need to duplicate a record in Rails, then it should be rendered into a new form before of creating the record.

Everything works following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12001940/1602464) helpful answer, but I'd need to populate the record with has_many_belongs_to_many associations as well

the method dup() let me duplicate everything in the record but its associations, I've also seen there's a gem [Amoeba](https://rubygems.org/gems/amoeba) that can do a very versatile deep cloning, but I wonder if there's a simpler solution without using a gem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails does not have built-in deep cloning. In Rails 2.3.x you had `clone` for cloning active record attributes. In Rails >3 they renamed this method to `dup`, and its documentation is now missing. However, it's identical to `clone` and its docs say the following.

> Note that this is a "shallow" clone: it copies the object’s attributes
>   only, not its associations. The extent of a "deep" clone is
>   application-specific and is therefore left to the application to
>   implement according to its need.

So if you want to clone associations, you are on your own. In my projects I used a method called `replicate` for this purpose.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def replicate
    replica = dup

    comments.each do |comment|
      replica.comments << comment.dup
    end

    replica
  end
end
```

Something along these lines.

Comment: Shouldn't it be replica.comments << comment.dup?

Comment: @Experience right, if you want to dup everything. In my case I was cloning user and moving associated data to the new one. Not 100% sure what OP wanted, but I made the edit as you suggested, cause that does seem more appropriate for the topic.