# How to link to controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12001940/2711219) on how to clone a record.

I can't though workout how to phrase the link and route it.

It is in my @miniature show view so I thought it should be something like

```
<%= link_to 'clone', :controller => :miniatures_controller, :action => :clone %>
```

and the route

```
  match 'clone', to: 'miniatures#clone', via: 'get'
```

but this is clearly wrong. I am using @miniature in place of the above answer's @prescription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you just use `clone_path`:

```
<%= link_to 'clone', clone_path %>
```

Cause `rake routes` shows just `clone` route. It works with the same routes.

If you are not satisfied with route and you should pass parameters (like `miniature_id`), add member to your resource (probably nested), like:

```
resources :miniatures do
  member do
    get 'clone'
  end
end
```

This will be `clone_miniature_path` where you should pass `@miniature`:

```
<%= link_to 'clone', clone_miniature_path(@miniature) %>
```

Comment: That works I think. My new form is making it crash now but the second code you gave works. clone_miniature_path. Great. Thank you so much.